# Weird bug on bash autocompletion since updating to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

I just updated to Ubuntu 17.04, and everything seems fine, except that now the bash auto-completion (for any command) colors weirdly its output.

Here is a small overview:

[image: prefix coloring]

Does anyone have any idea where this issue could come from, and if possible an idea to fix it ?

Or maybe it's not an issue, but a new feature in bash completion, to highlight the current pattern in the output (see how `file` is first highlighted, then only `fi` and then only `f`).
Any reference on this new feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the `colored-completion-prefix` readline option that was introduced in Readline 7.0 (released together with Bash 4.4), see the [release notes](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-09/msg00018.html).

To turn it off, you have to find where it's set, typically `~/.inputrc` or the value of the `$INPUTRC` environment variable, and turn it off.

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-colored_002dcompletion_002dprefix):

> `colored-completion-prefix`
>   If set to `on`, when listing completions, Readline displays the common prefix of the set of possible completions using a different color. The color definitions are taken from the value of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. The default is `off`.